# Control how EF materializes my data

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

Sometimes I want to do code based transformations on the data returned from my DB (for example [calculating a final product price](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6885838/794234)).  Putting such a transformation into my IQueryable directly results in the all too common:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'method name' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

I know I can execute the query and perform the projection completely in memory using `AsEnumerable` or `ToList`, but that would cause *two* passes over the data!

1. Loading the data from the DB and materializing it into the entity type
2. Converting the data (in memory) from the entity type into the final projection

EF *anyways* has to materialize the data *in memory*, so the second pass seems very redundant.  Is there a way to instruct EF "use this part of the expression tree for materializing the final object"?

** As  side note, would it be practical for the EF team to implement an automatic version of this functionality?  Namely, any part of any expression which could not be translated would be executed in the materialization stage instead?

Answer (score 0):

IMO messing with the materialization would lead to some unclear code. Consider this:

```
// Name should always be Bob.
EF.ChangeMaterialization<PersonEntity>(p => new PersonEntity { Name = "Bob" });

// What is supposed to happen here? The database clearly says that there are
// multiple Joe's in my People table, but once I retrieve them they are no
// longer Joe's! 
var query = People.Where(p => p.Name == "Joe");
```

Even if you have less contrived examples of why you might need this, it will still likely cause some confusion down the road. I suggest one of these options:

1. Create *different* properties that do the transformation you want and mark them as `Unmapped`.
2. If you are doing this because you want some sort of logic incorporated, create a layer of different transformed entities so you aren't locked into using them.
3. Use computed fields in your db and map them to entity properties. This might be the best option since you can still use them in queries.

Examples:

1:

```
public class Person {
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Unmapped]
    public string CalculatedName { get { return "Bob"; } }
}
```

2:

```
public class Student {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Grade { get; set; }
}

public class StudentRepository {
    public IEnumerable<Student> GetStudents() {
        return db.People.Select(p => new Student
            {
                Name = p.Name,
                Grade = p.Tests.Average()
            });
    }
}
```

3: Google: EF Computed Column for some examples.